# Modern energy management systems process huge amounts of data that can be difficult to manage without appropriate tools and approaches

Tags: python, pandas, database

HEEELP PLS!!!!!! It is important to take into account that the new software solution should be able to integrate with existing systems in the company.
Needs: The system should be able to automatically collect data from counters and analyze them. For the convenience of users, it is important to provide intuitive tools for visualizing energy consumption data. The system should be able to send notifications about anomalies in power consumption and generate reports for internal and external use. The use of machine learning and artificial intelligence methods can help in predicting future energy consumption and optimizing energy costs. The system should provide the ability to monitor and manage energy consumption in real time, allowing you to quickly respond to changes and optimize the use of resources. there is a large set of data related to energy consumption that needs preprocessing and analysis. Your task includes data cleaning, date processing, data visualization, as well as the application of machine learning methods to predict energy consumption.

As I understand it, you have problems with the dates recorded by the formula and you would like to see how to pre-process the data before clearing.
it is necessary to prepare a database that is further to machine learning

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split


df = pd.read_excel('/content/LAST.xlsx')


df['Дата_время'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Дата'].astype(str) + ' ' + df['Время'].str.split(' - ').str[0], errors='coerce')


df = df.drop(['Дата', 'Время'], axis=1)

df = df.dropna(thresh=df.shape[0]*0.5, axis=1)

df = df.dropna()

X = df.drop('Генерация, кВт', axis=1)
y = df['Генерация, кВт']

scaler = StandardScaler()
X_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_scaled, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
```

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.read_excel(r'/content/LAST.xlsx')
df.head()

df['date'] = df['Дата'].map(lambda x: x.strftime('%d.%m.%Y') if type(x) is pd.Timestamp else x) + ' ' + df['Время'].map(lambda x: x.split(' - ')[1])
df.date = df.date.map(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M'))
df.head()

def combine_date_time(df, datecol, timecol):
    return pd.to_datetime(df[datecol].dt.date.astype(str)+' '+df[timecol].dt.hour.astype(str)+':'+df[timecol].dt.minute.astype(str))

df["Month"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Дата"]).dt.month
df["Year"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Дата"]).dt.year
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Дата"]).dt.date
df["Time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Время"].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))  # Исправлено
df["Week"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Дата"]).dt.isocalendar().week  # Исправлено
df["Day"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Дата"]).dt.day_name()
df = df.set_index("Дата")
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

df = df.drop(columns=df.iloc[:, 5:65])  
df.columns = ['Datetime', 'Рынок план', 'Рынок факт', 'Генерация', 'Потребление комбината', 'Простой', 'Дата (начало)', 'Время (начало)', 'Дата (конец)', 'Время (конец)']  # проверьте соответствие количества столбцов
df.head()
```

[database](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eBXBGHI1hDYHxytb5h0vTMOHzSXFH0G5/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=112152338718245284255&rtpof=true&sd=true)